# Why "TypeError: Cannot read property 'airline' of undefined" when it is defined?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, object, nested

I'm trying to access the nested objects of my data array. It was working and all of a sudden, it started returning a **"TypeError: Cannot read property 'airline' of undefined"**. I checked, I can't seem to find anything I touched anywhere.

I have this data, when I tried to access `console.log(tempflights[0])`, the data is returned, but when I do `console.log(tempFlights[0].airline)`, or any other object property in the array, it returns a **type error**.

I'm also trying to compare the stored data with a received data to see if there's a match.

Can anyone help me figure out where I'm getting it wrong. 
Note: I'm very new to React and Js.

```js
import logo1 from "./images/delta.png";
import img1 from "./images/w1.jpg";


export default [
  {
    sys: {
      id: "1"
    },
    fields: {
      from: {
        destination: "London",
        slug: "LHR",
      },
      to: {
        destination: "New York",
        slug: "LGA",
      },
      airline: {
        name: "Delta",
        airlineId: "DL 214",
        logo:
        {
          fields: {
            file: {
              url: logo1
            }
          }
        }

      },
      tripClass: "economy",
      direct: true,
      stopOver: {
        destination: "",
        slug: ""
      },
      minPrice: 900,
      departureDate: "2020-06-05",
      roundTrip: true,
      returnDate: "2020-07-05",
      luggageLimit: 50,
      totalDuration: "6h 30m",
      featured: true,
      images: [
        {
          fields: {
            file: {
              url: img1
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
]


import React, { Component, createContext } from 'react'
import items from './data'



const DestinationContext = createContext();
// create context Provider

class DestinationProvider extends Component {
    //set up state
    state = {
        destinations: [],
        sortedDestinations: [],
        featuredDestinations: [],
        loading: true,
    }
 
    componentDidMount() {
        let destinations = this.formatData(items)
        let featuredDestinations = destinations.filter(destination =>
            destination.featured === true);

        this.setState({
            destinations,
            featuredDestinations,
            sortedDestinations: destinations,
            loading: false
        })
    }

    formatData(items) {
        let tempItems = items.map(item => {
            let id = item.sys.id
            let images = item.fields.images.map(image => image.fields.file.url);

            let destination = { ...item.fields, images, id }
            return destination;
        })
        return tempItems;
    }

    getFlights = (to, from, departureDate) => {
        let tempFlights = [...this.state.destinations];
        console.log(tempFlights[0].airline);

        const flight = tempFlights.filter(flight =>

            flight.to.destination.toLowerCase() === to.toLowerCase() &&
            flight.from.destination.toLowerCase() === from.toLowerCase() &&
            flight.departureDate >= departureDate
        );
        return flight;
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <DestinationContext.Provider value={{
                ...this.state,
                getFlights: this.getFlights
            }}>
                {this.props.children}
            </DestinationContext.Provider>
        );
    }
}
const DestinationConsumer = DestinationContext.Consumer;

export { DestinationProvider, DestinationConsumer, DestinationContext };
```

**Error:**

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'airline' of undefined
>   DestinationProvider.getFlights src/context.js:52 > 52 |
>   console.log(tempFlights[0].airline); | ^ 53 | 54 | const flights =
>   tempFlights.filter(flight => 55 | View compiled Flights.render
>   src/pages/Flights.js:24 21 | const { getFlights } = this.context 22 |
>   const slug = Object.fromEntries(new URLSearchParams(this.state.slug))
>   23 | const { to, from, departureDate } = slug > 24 | const flights =
>   getFlights(to, from, departureDate)

Comment: Just at a quick glance, wouldn't it be `tempflights.fields.airline`?

Comment: @Redline thanks for your quick response. As you can see, the data is flattened in this line: `let destination = { ...item.fields, images, id }` so the fields is bypassed when accessing.

Comment: `console.log(tempflights[0])` vs `console.log(tempFlights[0].airline)`. Be careful about the casing on `tempflights` when debugging. `tempFlights` and `tempflights` are different variables. That said... the code block looks reasonable and consistently uses `tempFlights` in my recklessly fast reading.

Comment: @HPierce I believe the error was when typing the question, not in the code

Comment: plz, Can you show me the error message?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'airline' of undefined
DestinationProvider.getFlights
src/context.js:52

> 52 | console.log(tempFlights[0].airline);
     | ^  53 | 
  54 | const flights = tempFlights.filter(flight =>
  55 | 
View compiled
Flights.render
src/pages/Flights.js:24
  21 | const { getFlights } = this.context
  22 | const slug = Object.fromEntries(new URLSearchParams(this.state.slug))
  23 | const { to, from, departureDate } = slug
> 24 | const flights = getFlights(to, from, departureDate)

@Michael

Answer (score 0):

As it is i still don't know why I can't access those objects from within the function, but I finally figured out why my filter function suddenly started returning an empty array.

I'm trying to compare these three values in the filter function,

```
 const flights = tempFlights.filter(flight =>
            flight.from.destination.toLowerCase() === from.toLowerCase() &&
            flight.to.destination.toLowerCase() === to.toLowerCase() &&
            flight.departureDate >= departureDate
        );
```

but the last comparison was wrong. I was supposed to compare 
`flight.departureDate <= departureDate.toString()`
Not 
`flight.departureDate >= departureDate`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `tempFlights[0] is undefined` because it is undefined (`this.state.destinations` is `[]` - initial state) at the moment you are trying to acsess (or log) it.

But note that it would be **defined** after a while i.e. when `componentDidMount` has executed and `setState` has been called.

```
  getFlights = (to, from, departureDate) => {
    let tempFlights = [...this.state.destinations]
    console.log(tempFlights[0].airline) // Error: tempFlights[0] is undefined

    const flight = tempFlights.filter(
      (flight) =>
        flight.to.destination.toLowerCase() === to.toLowerCase() &&
        flight.from.destination.toLowerCase() === from.toLowerCase() &&
        flight.departureDate >= departureDate
    )
    return flight
  }
```

If you initialize your state inside constructor like this, you should not see `Error: tempFlights[0] is undefined` inside `getFlights`. But I don't think you can do that as `items` would not really be a fixed / hardcoded value as you provide in this example. But I think your state will be set at `componentDidMount` and the changes would propagate correctly, so there should be no further error if you just remove console log in `getFlight` because at that moment it is really trying to read from undefined.

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    let destinations = this.formatData(items)
    let featuredDestinations = destinations.filter(
      (destination) => destination.featured === true
    )
    this.state = {
      destinations,
      featuredDestinations,
      sortedDestinations: destinations,
    }
  }
```